# How to set the default option of <select> according to state in JSX?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

```
state = {
      option: 'west'
    }

render(){
  return(
    <select>
      <option value="east">East</option>
      <option value="south">South</option>
      <option value="west">West</option>
      <option value="north">North</option>
    </select>
  )
}
```

How to set the default option of  according to state in JSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

defaultValue

```
render(){
  return(
    <select defaultValue="west">
      <option value="east">East</option>
      <option value="south">South</option>
      <option value="west">West</option>
      <option value="north">North</option>
    </select>
  )
}
```

Comment: Excuse me  .  if I want to set options for "disabled" according to state, is it set like "disabled = "west"?